# Make a responsive line break for dynamic content?

Tags: html, css, line-breaks, word-wrap

I have tried almost everything from word-wrap, text-wrap, etc but not able to get this. I have  a simple webpage which loads notices with few parameters and display them in a simple frame.

Frame design and everything else is responsive, just the text being loaded from db wont break with screen size, thereby not allowing the background frame to shrink as well.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">   
<head>   
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">

<style>
/* Tablet Landscape */
@media screen and (max-width: 1060px) {
    #primary { width:67%; }
    #secondary { width:30%; margin-left:3%;}  
    #notice {
    padding: 0 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial;
    font-size: 11pt;
    background-color: #7bb9e0;
}
    .date, .valid, .class {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-align:left;
    display: block;
}
}

/* Tabled Portrait */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #primary { width:100%; }
    #secondary { width:100%; margin:0; border:none; }
    #notice {
    padding: 0 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial;
    font-size: 11pt;
    background-color: #7bb9e0;
}
    .date, .valid, .class {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-align:left;
    display: block;
}
}

/*Desktop*/
@media screen and (min-width: 1060px) {
    #notice {
    padding: 0 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 600px;
    height: auto;
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial;
    font-size: 11pt;
    background-color: #7bb9e0;
}
.date, .valid, .class {
    padding-right: 40px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
}

.title, .notice, .notice-footer {
    padding-top: 10px;
    #padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
p
{
   width: 100%;
   text-wrap:normal;
   overflow-wrap:break-word;
}
.title {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.notice-footer {
    border-top: 1px dashed #000;
    padding-top: 2px;
    text-align: center;
}

div.ui-datepicker{
 font-size:12px;
}
</style>

<?php
echo "<div id=\"notice\">";
        echo "<div class=\"title\">".$title."</div>";
        echo "<div class=\"notice\"><p>".$new."</p></div>";
        echo "<div class=\"notice-footer\">";
            echo "<span class=\"date\"><font color=\"CC0000\">Posted on: </font>  ".$pdat."</span>";
            echo "<span class=\"valid\"><font color=\"CC0000\">Valid within: </font>".$sdat." - ".$edat."</span>";
            echo "<span class=\"class\"><font color=\"CC0000\">Class Year: </font>".$row['class']."</span>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div><br><br>";
?>
```

Now whenever $new would contain a large line, it wont break with in accordance with the screen size, and thereby the background #notice frame would be as long as the line too, and wont shrink anymore like it would have done if long line wouldn't have been there.

A sample snapshot:
[image]

If I would resize the browser, the background frame would shrink only as far as word "website"

Comment: I've created a **[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/NWv6c/)**, but I'm not sure I understand what the problem is?

Comment: Well, did you simply copy paste my code and creat a fiddle?
Its working fine on it, but wont work on my code.
Please have a look at my complete code and tell me if you can find something which is not allowing it to work? http://pastebin.com/cCbpi4ga



The problem is that, on my code, it wont allow the background frame to shrink and wont break the line at all on real code.

Comment: Nothing stands out in the code as problematic. I've created a local copy of the code you provided but obviously I don't have the database so I can't see any notices. Go to the page with the broken blue box in your browser, right-click and View Source and then copy and paste that code into a new PasteBin, then I should be able to locate the issue.

Comment: @AdamMcElroy , I made a code where there wont be any database required, you may run it, here: [View Code](http://pastebin.com/QtMm4pgy)
This code is working perfectly fine when screen size is reduced, check this [screenshot](http://bit.ly/19wcQHG) out

But same wont work when this data is fetched from database. First i thought it has got something to do with mysql_real_escap_string, but no, i removed that and same error.
Here's a [screenshot](http://bit.ly/HTigpQ) from actual site

Comment: The [source](http://pastebin.com/6tvs166N) as you requested. 

You may dump this table (7-8 rows) in a test db and try it as well with real code I gave you earlier. Change login info for your db accordingly: [Download table](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zhcgbfh3kwb3xb3/notices.sql)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously PHP is preprocessed so it's by looking at the standard HTML that it's outputting that we can start to understand the problem.

All of the spaces in the content being pulled from the database are actually HTML space characters (`&nbsp;`) rather than clear spaces. This means that rather than being separate words, each bit of data is interpreted as being one really long string. In the longest line, the HTML looks like this:

```
List&nbsp;of&nbsp;Mentors&nbsp;for&nbsp;B.E.&nbsp;First&nbsp;Year&nbsp;Students&nbsp;(Section&nbsp;wise)&nbsp;has&nbsp;been&nbsp;uploaded&nbsp;on&nbsp;the&nbsp;college&nbsp;website.
```

rather than just:

```
"List of Mentors for B.E. First Year Students (Section wise) has been uploaded on the college website."
```

This is why all of the word-wrap properties you've been applying having been working. Technically, there's only one word!

Therefore, I'd suggest trying out using `htmlspecialchars_decode()` when you're echoing the code. For example:

```
echo "<div class=\"title\">". htmlspecialchars_decode($title) ."</div>";
```

A better solution would be to try to find out why the code is being inserted into the database with these special characters in in the first place but that is outside the scope of this question so this may be a solution in the meantime.

Comment: You're the man. :))
Though htmlspecialchars_decode($notice) didnt work. It was still printing &nbsp's, but I did nl2br() on the data fetched from DB and it worked. Thanks a lot for your help.